# RecyclerView and IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index #, size is #

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a simple RecyclerView and I want to remove those items onClick. I was continuously running into a crash depending on when I clicked on certain items in the list with the above error. If you're having similar issues, here's how I solved it:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, final int position)
```

Using position here is useful for some things, but if I used it when removing items from the list, it was causing a crash, instead using:

```
holder.getAdapterPosition();
```

resolved my issues immediately.